# Can i use more than 2GB of RAM in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I use Premium v2 P3V2 plan on Azure, which means that I have 14GB of RAM available. But the function stops execution and throws OutOfMemoryException when it reach 2GB of RAM usage.

**Is there way to configure Azure function to use more that 2GB of RAM?**

Tried to optimise function but even if i make function use less that 2GB it will break when two requests come in same time.

Comment: Sounds like your code is running in x86 mode.

Comment: Go to Functionapp's configuration and check if the platform is set to **32 Bit**. If yes, change it to **64 Bit**. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/GbWoIdS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@PravallikaKV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19991670/pravallika-kv).

Changing the platform to x64 helped.

> Configuration > General Settings > Platform

[image: Switching to 64 bit]